# Implementation when assigning multiple foreign keys to a column in SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I create a table with the following relevance:

```sql
CREATE TABLE "user" (
  "id" SERIAL UNIQUE PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
  "create_datetime" timestamp NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE "delete_user" (
  "history_id" SERIAL UNIQUE PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
  "id" int NOT NULL,
  "create_datetime" timestamp NOT NULL,
  "archive_datetime" timestamp NOT NULL
);


CREATE TABLE "user_log" (
  "id" SERIAL UNIQUE PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
  "user_id" int NOT NULL,
  "height" float NOT NULL,
  "weight" float NOT NULL,
  "create_datetime" timestamp NOT NULL
);

ALTER TABLE "user_log" ADD FOREIGN KEY ("user_id") REFERENCES "user" ("id");
ALTER TABLE "user_log" ADD FOREIGN KEY ("user_id") REFERENCES "delete_user" ("id");
```

But I don't know how to express this in sqlalchemy.

I implemented up to the part that can be implemented.

```py
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.types import DateTime, Integer, Float

Base = declarative_base()

class User(Base):
    __tablename__="user"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    
class DeleteUser(Base):
    __tablename__="delete_user"
    history_id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    id = Column(Integer, nullable=False)

class UserLog(Base):
    __tablename__="user_log"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    user_id = Column(Integer, nullable=False)
    height = Column(Float, nullable=False)
    weight = Column(Float, nullable=False)
    create_datetime = Column(DateTime, nullable=False)
```

And I want to associate the id of User and DeleteUser with the user_id of this UserLog.

What should I do?

Comment: You **can not have a single column reference more than a single table**.  You have not indicated that delete user actually is. Is it the user that took delete action on something in the  DB or is the user themself  has been deleted? With knowing that and how you plan on using it,  the only suggestion is create delete_user_id column in user_log. You then have each it reference the appropriate table.

Comment: The delete_user id and user id do not overlap.  When a user deletion request is issued, the user information is migrated to delete_user and the original user record is deleted.  Therefore, it is not necessary to separate the id of user_log from delete_user and user.  Sorry for the lack of explanation.

Comment: OK, but it still does not matter, `a single column can reference only a single table`. To reference another table **you must create another column**. In this case when you migrate the deleted user you must also update *user_log* either in the same statement or with deferred constraints in the same transaction. A much better approach (imho) would move the *archive_datetime* to the *user* table and use it as the not-deleted/deleted indicator and `eliminate deleted_user  table` If you need a list on just non-deleted users create a VIEW.

Comment: ok, i understood. thank you!